# Есть ли у мартышки хоть маленький суффикс?

Tags: словообразование, суффиксы, корень-слова

И каково ее происхождение? От марта, Марты или Мартына?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суффикс в русском языке не выделяют, хотя понятно, что образовано по модели "шалунишка", "мелочишка" и проч. Но основа Marten (герм. "Обезьяна") - и в русском однокоренных с мартышкой слов не породила.

*Фасмеру я сне перечу по сути, но точность передачи фонетики германских форм-источников я не могу проверить. Голландский вариант я что-то даже произнести не могу. Дифтонг в безударном слоге настораживает. Но это не здесь обсуждать.*

К именам Мартын, тем более - Марта, отношения не имеет, оба имени (прямо или опосредовано) восходят к римскому богу войны Марсу.

(+)

В связи с комментарием (см.) уточняю ответ. Библейское (ветхозаветное) **Марфа**, это конечно, отдельное имя, к римлянам отношения не и имеющее. Но к "мартышке" - тем более.

Comment: Комментарий: Мартин (он же наш Мартын) - восходит к Марсу-богу. Марфа (она же Марта) - библейское имя (сирийск. госпожа, хозяйка). Источники: Библия, словари Суперанской.

Comment: @alexsms Марфа (Martha) и Марта (Marta, Marte) - этимологически ***разные*** имена. Фонетическое сходство породило смешение Смешение. Впрочем, спасибо, оговорю в ответе.

Comment: Вообще-то Суперанская пишет, что Марфа и Марта - одно и то же. Марта - зап. форма (по аналогии с Федор-Теодор и т.п.)

Comment: @alexsms Ну, значит, неточная формулировка. Произошло смешение, а не "одно и то же". Сохранившийся римский вариант Марты - "Марсия". Я не отрицаю "Марфу"-"Марту" по Суперанской, но это совсем не полный ответ об этимологии, просто затасканный всеми источниками.

Comment: Здесь признается связь Марты с римским Марсом, хотя формулировоски тоже оставляют желать, они и "Мартину" дают две трактовки - еврейскую тоже. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marta_(given_name)

Comment: @Мимоходов. Эх, отняли у мартышки такое украшение! А ведь была надежда на какую-нибудь страшную легенду.

Comment: @ЕленаТаволга - )))) В этимологии отдельных слов очень мало "легенд". Как правило все ограничивается переосмыслением слова на основании сходного звучания, много реже - орфографической ошибки... Вот в идиоматике любопытные истории пусть и нечасто, но встречаются. Но это отдельная область.

Comment: @Мимоходов. 
- Ага! - Елена закатала рукава повыше и надвинула кокошник пониже. - Вот оно, поле невозделанное! Найдем сходство в звучании, переосмыслим, добавим орфографическую ошибку - и вуаля: страшная городская легенда готова. Пугайтесь на здоровье!)))

Answer (score 1):

Зная о заимствовании русск. *мартын*, *мартышка* ср.-нж.-нем. Маrtеn «обезьяна» или ср.-нидерл. Мartijn (по словарю М. Фасмера), предположу изначальную смысловую связь со словом *мартириане*, т. е. еретики, — от др.-греч. αἱρετικός от гл. αἱρέω «брать, хватать; выбирать». Последнее — из Полного СЦ-СЯ Г. Дьяченко.

Comment: Вот когда смотрю на обезьяну, особенно вблизи, думаю, как и вы: «Ну точно, вылитая мартирианка!» ;)))

Comment: Вблизи может быть. Но обычно — как обделённая речью, обезъязыченная, — на «немца».